# Error in h2o.predict: trying to get slot "model_id" from an object (class "H2OFrame") that is not an S4 object

Tags: r, h2o

I modeled an object using h2o. But, when I try to predict the test dataset using h2o.predict, the output is an error:

Error in paste0("Predictions/models/", object@model_id, "/frames/", h2o.getId(newdata)) : 
  trying to get slot "model_id" from an object (class "H2OFrame") that is not an S4 object

The test and train test are from the same dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `h2o.predict()` incorrectly.  The error indicates that you are trying to access the `model_id` slot on a H2OFrame (rather than on a model), which means you probably mixed up the order of the test set and model or just passed a test set (without a model).

Your code should look like:

```
preds <- h2o.predict(model, test)
```